# How to draw the dual of a quadrangle determined by four points?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, duality-theorems

Draw a quadrangle determined by the points $P, Q, R, S$ and name the sides and the three diagonal points $A, B,$ and $C$. Now draw the dual of this quadragle and name its sides and diagonals $a, b$, and $c$.